# spark-submit hangs after adding --py-files

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions, spark-submit, python-packaging

i have a script which was working fine. script have some UDF and in end save data to Hive table. Then i tried to modularize the script by putting UDF functin in different script under different folder. After doing that started getting error module doesnot exists. then tried packaging the module and passing it using --py-files. But after doing this script hangs for ever. If code is put in line instead of module then everything works fine
Folder structure is like

```
application
    utils
        src
            utility.py
    component
        src
            main_Script.py
```

In main_script.py I have

```
import utils.src.utility as local_util
```

utility.py
have udf func like

```
@func.udf("string")
def some_function:
    ...
    ..
    return 'xyz'
```

in main

many operation and then

```
from spark.sql import function as func
def main(df):
    df = df.withColumn('col1', local_utils.some_function(func.col('col2')))
```

then df is saved to hive table.
script is executed like\

```
spark-submit --queue xxx master yarn main.py
```

gets error module utils does not exists

on checking documentation it suggest to package utils and pass it as --py-files

so I zipped the utils and then passed it

spark-submit --queue xxx master yarn --py-files utils.zip main.py

on doing this job hangs for ever

if i put utils code in line in main.py and then run then everything works fine.

so wanted to know what is going wrong by using --py-files?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to pass entire path to utils file, like:

```
--py-files /home/user_name/project/utils.zip
```

utils.zip should have the same structure as python module with `__init__.py` files etc.